# IE9 text input with padding issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

In IE9 (I don't know about older versions, but first I need a solution for the scenario in IE9), the last letters in an `<input type="text" />` disappear behind the right padding, if so exists.

Please take a look at this fiddle (in IE9): http://jsfiddle.net/LQxDM/

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but... what exactly do you want it to do? The input has a fixed width, the font has a fixed size. Is this a static text or you are users going to input their emails?

Comment: Running into this same issue. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Apparent example of the issue, with nice screenshots: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14487

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a fixed width to your input field, it will not display text beyond that width. Here's another question that you might find useful. It updates the width of the input based on  its contents: [Resize input text field as text is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784078/resize-input-text-field-as-text-is-entered)

Answer (score -3):

Add to your styles

```
padding-right: 20px;
width: 320px;
```

Comment: @Erel -  Sorry didn't know this is a dynamic value.